# Significant Location updates after force quit in iOS app

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, ios8, cllocationmanager

I am currently tracking the user location updates for every mile travelled. And I have background mode turned on for app to look for location updates.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 

[NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        locationManager.delegate = self

        if iOS8 {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        } else {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }

        locationManager.distanceFilter = 1609.34 // meters in 1 mile
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        return true
    }
```

But, I am wondering, if the application has been force quit, I would still like for the application to be updating the location. Is that possible with `startUpdatingLocation` class? Or should I be using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`

I read the doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges) but didn't quite understand when to move from `startUpdatingLocation` to `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` when/while the app is being force quit. Should it be under `applicationWillTerminate` function ?

Or if that is even possible or is there something else i should be doing.

UPDATE:

I read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

> In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force
>   quit by the user. One exception is location apps, which in iOS 8 and
>   later are relaunched after being force quit by the user. In other
>   cases, though, the user must launch the app explicitly or reboot the
>   device before the app can be launched automatically into the
>   background by the system.

If thats the case, should I use `startUpdatingLocation` or move to `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` ?

Comment: Interested. It seems like if the user configured the location permission "Always", System relaunch the location app.

Comment: Document says "If an app is terminated for any reason other than the user force quitting it, the system launches the app when one of the following events happens:". I think that means the system relaunch the app only when the system killed the app forcibly. If the user quit the app, the app would not be relaunched.

Comment: @EIMEI - The user can *only* force quit an app by sliding up - there is no other "quit" option, so in the case of location services iOS will relaunch the app when required regardless of how/why it was terminated

Comment: @Paulw11 so, if the app was force quit by user (sliding up), the system will relaunch and it still update locations?

Comment: On ios8 yes, as per the documentation quoted in the question

Comment: "One exception is location apps, which in iOS 8 and later are relaunched after being force quit by the user" AND "If an app is terminated for any reason other than the user force quitting it, the system launches the app when one of the following events happens" It seems these are conflicting. I want to write samples for this issue.

Comment: Exactly. The doc is confusing. Hm, I will just go test and dive around the town a little I believe :)

Comment: @psharma Were you able to test the actual behavior on device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app was terminated, you could not run any program for the app.

And it's not always to handle applicationWillTerminate function when the app was terminated. In some situations, the system kills the app without any notification. Please read the document about application life cycle.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

I think you want to do your app is running like a daemon service. iOS does not allow us that unless the device is jail broken.

https://www.chrisalvares.com/blog/7/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-1/

If you are care of the device battery, you would to do like this.

- startUpdatingLocation and stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges at applicationWillEnterForeground.
- startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges and stopUpdatingLocation at applicationDidEnterBackground.

Comment: Why do you suggest switching between significant location changes and full location updates in `applicationWillResignActive`? `applicationWillEnterForeground:` would be a better method to do this in

Comment: @EIMEI, right but I battery saving is not a concern. We are focusing more on location updates as much as possible. So there is no way for the app to call ```didUpdateLocations``` when the app has been force quit? Interesting because the doc somehow means otherwise.

Comment: We have checked this case..We are getting location updates in simulator even after force quit..but when we check in iPhone, we don't get it. Did you find anything to work it ?